# Relative routes angular isn't working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a feature module, I am following the docs.

My crisis-routing.module seem like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CrisisCenterComponent } from './crisis-center.component';
import { CrisisListComponent } from './crisis-list/crisis-list.component';
import { CrisisDetailComponent } from './crisis-detail/crisis-detail.component';
import { CrisisCenterHomeComponent } from './crisis-center-home/crisis-center-home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CrisisCenterRoutingModule { }
```

I supposed that I would access to id with this:

```
 [routerLink]="['./crisis-center/..', crisis.id]"
```

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Angular has a preferred way of structuring params which have children pages. I would declare the routes like this:

```
children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'crisis-home',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

You can then access the route(s) using this:

```
[routerLink]="['./crisis-center/..', crisis.id, 'crisis-home']"
```

Which would give you:

```
localhost/crisis-center/1/crisis-home
```

Comment: I want to show each element from list in CrisisDetailComponent then I should set CrisisDetailComponent with :id. I think the problem is the way to access to that route. I have tried your post but I didn't get it.

Comment: Excuse my english, I am not native

Answer (score 0):

I have got that it work, but I don't get to work with nested children.

My new routes is now:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CrisisCenterComponent } from './crisis-center.component';
import { CrisisListComponent } from './crisis-list/crisis-list.component';
import { CrisisDetailComponent } from './crisis-detail/crisis-detail.component';
import { CrisisCenterHomeComponent } from './crisis-center-home/crisis-center-home.component';
import { CrisisDetailedComponent } from './crisis-detailed/crisis-detailed.component';

const crisisRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        // children: [
        //   { path: '', component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent },
        //   { path: 'crisis/:id', component: CrisisDetailedComponent },
        // ]
      },
      { path: ':id', component: CrisisDetailedComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(crisisRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CrisisCenterRoutingModule { }
```

I don't know why it's only accept one nested routes, perhaps I don't know to access to routes.